# Can't find the bug - too many firings

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

(edited some spelling errors)

So here's a piece of code that repeats itself with every answer the user gives to an MPC-question:

- It fires the question, generates 4 answers, binds 'click' and 'mouseover' to the answers, and waits for the user to actually click on one of them.
- When he does, it checks if it was right or wrong, displays that to the user, and then waits for another input (anywhere in the document, this time) before it proceeds and repeats.

Now, the idea is that a user can either click with the cursor, OR use QWER to answer. And as I'm am quite new to manipulation of an event and its data, I found a (flawed, apparently) way to separate the two, as you'll find below.

However, when a user 'answers' by clicking, and 'proceeds' by QWER, it waltzes through the whole thing too fast, by actually firing the question as intended, and then immediately answering it AND firing another question AGAIN. (And after extracting the time it takes for this into an array, I found that it sometimes does this 3-6 times in a row, with no apparent reason for this how many times at all...)

Now, as mentioned, I am new when it comes to events, so there may be redundancies and/or wrong uses of (e), but bear with me. I expect the bug to be related to this, of course. Also, some functions are irrelevant here, because they lead back to whatever function their call is in (right(); for example, does not fire anything after itself).

It's the loop that's the point here.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
function keyAns() {
    answered="no";
    draw(0);
}

function keyNotAns (A) {
    B = $(A).children('.answer');
    if ($(B).hasClass('right')) {
        // do something
    }
    else if ($(B).hasClass('wrong')) {
        // do something
    }
    answered = "yes";
}

function waitForInput() {

    // MOUSE CLICK
    $(document).click(function() {
        if (answered == "yes") {
            answered = "no";
            draw(0);
        }
    });

    $('.answer').click(function(e) {
        $('.answer').unbind('click');
        if (answered == "no") {
            calcTime(1);

            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
                // do something
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('wrong')) {
                // do something
            }
            answered = "yes";
        }
    });

    // KEYPRESSES
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
        $(document).unbind('keyup');
        if (answered == "yes") {
            e.stopPropagation();
            keyAns();
        }
        else if ( answered == "no") {
            calcTime(1);    // irrelevant

            if(e.which == 81 || e.keyCode == 81) { // Q
                AAA = '#ansQ';
                e.stopPropagation();
                keyNotAns(AAA);
            }
            else if(e.which == 87 || e.keyCode == 87) { // W
                AAA = '#ansW';
                e.stopPropagation();
                keyNotAns(AAA);
            }
            else if(e.which == 69 || e.keyCode == 69) { // E
                AAA = '#ansE';
                e.stopPropagation();
                keyNotAns(AAA);
            }
            else if(e.which == 82 || e.keyCode == 82) { // R
                AAA = '#ansR';
                e.stopPropagation();
                keyNotAns(AAA);
            }
            else {
            }
            waitForInput();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Hehehehe the title of this question made me laugh.. "Argh, all the previous developers were fired and their code is a mess, halp!" ^_^

Comment: I'm guessing from the fact that you receive any events at all, you must have at least one other place where you call `waitForInputs()`.  When do those calls occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

All thanks to **Scott Mermelstein** and **ColBeseder**, both equally invaluable to my solution! Not only did they find the flaws, they made me understand how **events** and **binds** work. So thanks a million, you two!

Indeed:

- binds were being stacked, therefore IF it fired, it would fire excessively, also;
- the self-call of waitForinput() was indeed unneeded, however;
- one e.stopPropagation() was also needed, to prevent the loop from working with wrong event-data, which lead the function to interpret it as the next answer and fire itself again.

Plus: due to laziness - I didn't feel like too much trial and error - I wanted to stay on the safe side, so I added all unbind()'s as first-thing when the function fires.

The result, which works flawlessly, for those who're interested:

```
function keyNotAns (A) {
    B = $(A).children('.answer');
    if ($(B).hasClass('right')) {
        // do something
    }
    else if ($(B).hasClass('wrong')) {
        // do something
    }
    answered = "yes";
}

function waitForInput() {
    $(document).unbind('keyup');
    $(document).unbind('click');
    $('.answer').unbind('click');

    // MOUSE CLICKS
    $(document).click(function() {
        if (answered == "yes") {
            answered = "no";
            draw(0);
        }
    });

    $('.answer').click(function(e) {
        if (answered == "no") {
            calcTime(1);
            if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
                // do something
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('wrong')) {
                // do something
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
            answered = "yes";
        }
    });

    // KEYPRESSES
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
        if (answered == "yes") {
            answered="no";
            draw(0);
        }
        else if (answered == "no") {
            if(e.which == 81 || e.keyCode == 81) { // Q
                keyNotAns('#ansQ');
            }
            else if(e.which == 87 || e.keyCode == 87) { // W
                keyNotAns('#ansW');
            }
            else if(e.which == 69 || e.keyCode == 69) { // E
                keyNotAns('#ansE');
            }
            else if(e.which == 82 || e.keyCode == 82) { // R
                keyNotAns('#ansR');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time that there's a keypress event, you rebind everything.

This means that if you push 10 keys, you will have 10 `onclick` listeners. So when a user then clicks, the callback will run 10 times in a row.

The code that you posted doesn't include the original call to the waitForInput function, but you only need to call it once, so you can delete it from this code.

**A quick introduction to jquery events:**

When you `bind`, every time that event occurs (on the element you put it to), the callback function you provided will run.

Another tip is that in more recent versions of jQuery, there in an alternative to bind named `one`. It does the same, but it will only run the first time. Although in this situation, you don't need it.

Comment: Profit! This is why IF it bugs, it bugs X times in a row! Thanks for this. Now the bug itself (which I think Scott has nailed!).

Comment: But I unbind as well. As soon as waitForInput() is called, it binds keyup/click to elements, but when you actually keyup or click, it is immediately unbound again, right? Or did I miss something, or done something wrong?

Comment: Every time you call waitForInput, you bind three event (document click, .answer click, document keyup). Everytime there's a keyup, you unbind keyup, but not the clicks. then you bind the clicks again. This is why you end up with a whole bunch of click event listeners.

You're right that if you did unbind on all three each time, you would be fine. But there's no need for this unbinding and rebinding. You only need to bind once.

Comment: You are right. Question, though: the elements are deleted and recreated. Is rebinding, then, still not needed? Thanks for the help, man!

Comment: Usually it is. I haven't seen that part of your code. But aparently you're rebinding without deleting. Clearly you're not deleting the document. As an aside, you can use jQuery's `.on()` or `.delegate()` to persist even when elements are removed or added.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that inside your keybind, you're calling `waitForInput`.

Asynchronous programming takes some getting used to, but what the functions do inside waitForInput is set up event listeners, and *any time* the event happens, those listeners fire.

The problem you're seeing is that after handling an event, you're adding more event listeners, and next time the event fires, the listener will fire multiple times.

Simply take the `waitForInput()` line out of the function, and put it at the bottom of your code.  Then it will run only once, and you'll be fine.  (It wouldn't hurt to rename it to something like `setupEventListeners`, to avoid confusion.)

Comment: However, I unbind them as well, right as an input is given. Plus, the answer-elements are deleted after the user 'proceeds', so the newly generated div's have to be rebound to the 'clicks' and 'mouseovers', right?

Comment: You unbind 2 of your 3 events; the issue might be coming from the fact that you don't unbind the `document.click()`.  In that case, after pressing a key, you have two or more events handling document.click().  I'd say try moving the `waitForInput()` call, and see if you still have any problems.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to find such bugs. The first one is using the debugger - which can be pretty tedious when you have loops.

The second approach is logging: Write a report / log of all the important actions that you can read later to find out why it failed at some point in the past.

Have a look at `console.log()` or a [JavaScript logging framework](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Javascript_Logging_Frameworks).

Comment: Why is this an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: Because this is a help site, not a coding site. We help people to understand and solve their problems by themselves, we don't debug code for them (unless the problem is obvious). (+1 for your answer, btw.)

Comment: Aaron, thanks for this info - I'll study this. However, regardless of your valid point, it's not a direct answer to the question (even though it might not be an ideal type of question!), so I won't vote for it.

Comment: If you were a first time poster, someone reviewing your answer would tag it as "this is more appropriate as a comment".  It is helpful, but doesn't directly answer the OP's direct question.  Is it then appropriate to answer every question with "debug or log"?

Comment: I agree with Aaron, would like to add this http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820